# Why can an object rest not be inferred as an acceptable instance of a generic?

Tags: typescript, generics

Sorry if this is a dupe, either it hasn't been asked or my google-fu wasn't strong enough to find it.

Consider the following code:

```
type MyType = {
    a: string;
}

function f<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(x: T): T {
    return x;
}

function g<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(fn: (x: T) => T): (y: T & MyType) => void {
    return function(y) {
        const { a, ...rest } = y;
        console.log(`got ${a} for a`);
        fn(rest); // ERROR
    }
}
```

Since here `y` is type `T & MyType` and I'm pulling out the `MyType` part with destructuring logically AFAICT the rest should be whatever the generic type `T` is.

I can think of two reasons why this error might happen:

1. There might be an `a` property in `T` and pulling it out makes it a potentially invalid `T`.
2. The compiler just isn't smart enough to figure this out.

Which (if either!) is correct? And how should I write this? I guess I could always just pass the extra in `y` on to `fn`...

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQIYC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwG4MBfDDAMwFdKBjYcge0qgsAPPCgQAHsAiUAJkSgAlCJ16kZQkhRoAaKBwDWlXgHdKAPjMAKcYXgBKW+iw5SEYG1IDx9Jqw7c+AWoRMUlpOUVlVXVNKmpdAyNTC0sWSkJrWzsoZDMoewyQRwAyWAQkbNyoADdechknHChXd09Bfx5+SxBszCamlUoSdDxdADoJ12GGHKgQen6cQaJeABsIMdXeaksAA2peYCgAEjRcGZZVPF27BcXBSksp4FvnbCYmIA)

Comment: In the case where `T` has a property `a`, `rest` is no longer a `T`, so yes, the first reason. Passing `y` is allowed since `T & MyType` is assignable to `T`, even if `T` already has a property `a`. If you don't need `a` in the callback anyways, you could use `Omit` to make `fn(rest)` valid: https://tsplay.dev/mbv1dm

Comment: @pink that's an answer, feel free to write it as one!

Comment: Imagine what happens if you use `g<{a:string, b:string}>`. The `rest` has type `{b:string}`, but your `fn` expects the same `T` as in the definition of `g`, namely `{a:string, b:string}`.